# cannot git pull on a checked out branch in jgit

Tags: git, jgit

With jgit, I cloned the master branch of a git repo, and I then I checked out a remote branch with this

```
git.checkout()
.setCreateBranch(true)
.setName(branch)
.setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK)
.setStartPoint(s"origin/$branch")
.setForce(true)
.call()
```

I then tried to git pull on this branch,

git.pull().call()

but ended up with this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: No value for key branch.X.Y.Z.merge found in configuration
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:217)
at com.baml.cesium.sphinx.token.TestGIT$delayedInit$body.apply(TestGIT.scala:52)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
at com.baml.cesium.sphinx.token.TestGIT$.main(TestGIT.scala:15)
at com.baml.cesium.sphinx.token.TestGIT.main(TestGIT.scala)
```

I found out the checked out branch is not updated in .git/config, which is probably the reason for this error message. So can that config be somehow updated with the checkout, or does jgit actually allow git pull on a checked out branch at all?

(I know I can clone a branch directly with jgit, but I still want to find out the answer for the above)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also include the contents of `.git/config` here?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting that configuration beforehand:

```
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("branch", "master", "merge", "refs/heads/master");
```